# possibilities to play OGG in UWP

Tags: uwp, naudio, ogg

I am developing app on Universal Windows Platform to play audio files. I could not find way to play OGG files using MediaElement or AudioGraph. Therefore I was about to first convert the ogg to some supported format. Can you give me a hint what would work on UWP? I tried NAudio to convert from OGG to WAV but the NVorbis part is not yet translated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Vote on uservoice: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/17890894-add-ogg-vorbis-opus-to-audioencodingproperties

Answer (score 1):

MediaElement or AudioGraph does not support OGG files by default. To play OGG files, you have to implement the corresponding decoder. This won't be a easy task.

One easy way to achieve what you want is using some existing decoders that can be used in UWP such as [VLC.MediaElement for UWP](https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement). It's very easy to use. Just add the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VLC.MediaElement) to your project and use it as the classic MediaElement.

```
xmlns:vlc="using:VLC"
```

```
<vlc:MediaElement AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" HardwareAcceleration="True"
                  Source="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi">
    <vlc:MediaElement.TransportControls>
        <vlc:MediaTransportControls ControlPanelOpacity="0.8" />
    </vlc:MediaElement.TransportControls>
</vlc:MediaElement>
```

The difference here is that, `VLC.MediaElement` can only accept a `string` for the `Source` property. If you want to play a local file, you need to add the file into [FutureAccessList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions#Windows_Storage_AccessCache_StorageApplicationPermissions_FutureAccessList) to get the `FILE_TOKEN` and then set the source with `winrt://{FILE_TOKEN}` protocol.

```
var fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
var file = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    var FILE_TOKEN = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);
    mediaElement.Source = null;
    mediaElement.Source = $"winrt://{FILE_TOKEN}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation for it, but if you use `Windows::Media::Core::MediaSource::CreateFromStream(ogg_stream, "audio/ogg");` it will actually work and allow you to play OGG streams. Due to it being undocumented, I am not sure how reliable it actually is, but it works fine in my testing surprisingly. If anyone finds official Microsoft documentation for this OGG support, please comment it or update this answer to link to it.

Here is some example code for it in C++/CX:

```cpp
auto create_ogg_media_node(Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream ^ogg_stream, Windows::Media::Audio::AudioGraph ^graph)
-> Windows::Media::Audio::MediaSourceAudioInputNode ^
{
    Windows::Media::Core::MediaSource ^source = Windows::Media::Core::MediaSource::CreateFromStream(ogg_stream, "audio/ogg");
    Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<Windows::Media::Audio::CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeResult ^> ^task = graph->CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeAsync(source);
    Windows::Media::Audio::CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeResult ^result = task->GetResults();
    assert(result->Status == Windows::Media::Audio::MediaSourceAudioInputNodeCreationStatus::Success);
    return result->Node;
}
```

From there you would call `AddOutgoingConnection` on the returned node to point it to where you want it to go in your `AudioGraph`.